# Check if a combination of fields already exists in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

My weakest area of SQL are self JOINS, currently struggling with an issue.

I need to find the latest entry in a table, I'm using a `WHERE DATEFIELD IN (SELECT MAX(DATEFIELD) FROM TABLE)` to do this. I then need to establish if 3 columns from that already exist in the same TABLE.

My latest attempt looks like this -

```
SELECT * FROM PART_TABLE
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT 
t1.DATEFIELD
t1.CODE1
t1.CODE2
t1.CODE3
FROM PART_TABLE t1
INNER JOIN PART_TABLE t2 ON t1.UNIQUE = t2.UNQIUE
)
WHERE t1.DATEFIELD IN
(
SELECT MAX(DATEFIELD)
FROM PARTTABLE
)
```

)

I think part of the issue is that I can't exclude the unique row from t1 when checking in t2 using this method.

Using MSSQL 2014.

Comment: If the table has one row with a UNIQUE value which is not null, the sub-query will be true - and no rows at all returned.

Comment: Why you are using `IN` there since the `SELECT MAX(DATEFIELD)` will return just one row?

Comment: Take smaller steps. Add one condition, does it work? Add another condition etc.

Comment: @Sami I had more comparisons at one point, reduced to a single one now, so yes, should have changed that to `=`. I've went down a rabbit hole at this point and probably need to start with a fresh sheet.

Comment: @jarlh Good advice, I will deconstruct and start again

Comment: If you use EXISTS on the same table then you need to exclude the same record in the EXISTS query. F.e. `select * from tbl t1 WHERE exists (select 1 from tbl t2 where t2.field = t1.field AND t2.id <> t1.id)`. Else there would exist a match by default.

Comment: @LukStorms comment is better.Although, you could also keep your join but not with your unique, with the eg "code1" and after to and all others your final where clause. (this is not the best)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query will return the latest record from your table and a bit flag whether a duplicate tuple `{Code1, Code2, Code3}` exists in it under a different identifier:

```
select top (1) p.*,
  case when exists (
    select 0 from dbo.Part_Table t where t.Unique != p.Unique
    and t.Code1 = p.Code1 and t.Code2 = p.Code2 and t.Code3 = p.Code3
  ) then 1
  else 0 end as [IsDuplicateExists]
from dbo.Part_Table p
order by p.DateField desc;
```

You can use this example as a template to address your specific needs, which unfortunately aren't immediately apparent from your explanation.